# Geocoding Google Api returns 1 result for ambiguous address

Tags: java, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using java sdk Geocoding Google Api, to fetch Geocoding information using address.

When I use google maps UI, and enter "1 rue de Paris" I get multiple results in different cities and was expecting the sdk to return more than 1 result also but it's only returning 1.

My code:

```
GeocodingResult[] results = GeocodingApi.geocode(context, "1 rue de Paris").await()
```

`results` contains only 1 element.

what did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "google maps UI", are you talking about the Place Autocomplete list of place suggestions you get when you type in this address in Google Maps?

If so, note that what you're using is Geocoding API, not Places API. [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) is meant to be used for converting addresses into coordinates and vice-versa, and often returns only 1 place.

If you want to get a list of places, use the [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) service:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=1%20rue%20de%20Paris&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is it returning an array in this case if it's 0 or 1 result?

Comment: Regardless of the number of predictions, the "predictions" parameter is always an array, and is always returned (empty or otherwise). :) You can find more info in this section https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_responses